# How to start a freelance career (during retirement) in programming with a background in data warehousing

Tags: freelance-websites, working-from-home

I just retired with over 30 years of software development experience in the business intelligence and data warehousing area of IT.
I would like to keep my skills up to date and work part-time in the data warehousing area.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to start freelance career as a data warehouse consultant?
I prefer to work from home but that is not a deal breaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try site focused on offering freelancer services, which you can find out making a search on Google.

References:

> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=data+warehouse+freelancer

> ***Just a suggestion:** but if you wish to freelancing the best advice I
> can give you at the moment is to try change your skillset to Web
> Development focused on Wordpress and Woocommerce, that way you will
> get more freelancing jobs. Even because with the COVID outbreak the
> e-commerce tendency has drastically risen to due that I just
> mentioned. With that way will be more easy to make money quickly as
> freelancer dev.*

Comment: Good input.  I am retired so I have a steady income. Why do you suggest WordPress/WooCommerce over other web dev stacks?  Would not being a JavaScript Full Stack developer or Python Web developer work as well?

Comment: Because almost any hosting provider tends offering mainly WP based hosting plans but you could also get good opportunities going with Python. But in that latter, a little bit less when compared against WP related ones.